# The program expected this account to be already initialized (anchor solana)

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

When I do anchor build, the compiler return this error caused by mint, ownerTokenAccount and buyerTokenAccount. Here is my code:

```
    let minter = await splToken.createMint(connection, wallet.payer, wallet.publicKey, null, 1)
    const tokenAccount = // create token account
    // minted 1 nft
    const buyer: anchor.web3.Keypair = // get keypair from file
    const buyerTokenAddress = await anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
      mint: minter,
      owner: buyer.publicKey,
    });
    await program.methods.buyNft(
      new anchor.BN(saleAmount)
    )
      .accounts({
        mint: minter,
        ownerTokenAccount: tokenAccount.address,
        ownerAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
        buyerTokenAccount: buyerTokenAddress,
        buyerAuthority: buyer.publicKey,
      }).signers([buyer]).rpc();
```

and this is the code in my contract:

```
pub fn buy_nft(
        ctx: Context<BuyNft>,
        // amount: Option<u64>,
        lamports: Option<u64>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            lamports.unwrap(),
        )?;
        associated_token::create(CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
            associated_token::Create {
                payer: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                associated_token: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            },
        ))?;
        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyNft<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
}
```

In my version, the rent param in associated_token::Create is not existed so I remove it. So can you help me fixing this bug? Thanks

Comment: is that the full contract code?

Comment: @Yilmaz I just add struct context in the contract and I think this part of the code is enough that matter this issue. Cuz too much code will raise error that this question is full of code.